# d3 force layout initial structure

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is it is possible to give a d3 force layout some kind of structure? I wanting to show the relationship between staff and users, staff can have many users.

However the initial layout while correct is incomprehensible.

[image]

The nodes with red outlines are staff, and blue outlines are users, ideally it would be nice to have users below that staff, almost in a force hierarchy layout if they exist?

```
var width = document.querySelector('.visualisation').clientWidth,
        height = 500;

    var svg = d3.select(".visualisation").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(.05)
        .linkDistance(100)
        .charge(-300)
        .size([width, height]);

    var sw  = [],
        su = [],
        workbase = [],
        links = [],
        edges = [],
        simplified = [];

    d3.json("test_example.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error) throw error;
        console.log(json);
        var users = [];
        json.forEach(function(data){
            if(data.workbase == "Cherry Tree Lodge") {
                data.weight = 1;
                links.push({
                    target : data.user_id,
                    source : data.staff_id,
                });
                users.push(data);
            }
        });

        console.log(nodes);

        // json.forEach(function(data) {

        // console.log(json);
        users.forEach(function(d) {
            if(_.findWhere(sw, { name: d.staff_name}) == undefined) {
                sw.push({ 
                    name : d.staff_name,
                    id : d.staff_id,
                    role : d.role,
                    weight:1,
                    type : "worker"
                });
            }
            if(_.findWhere(su, { name: d.service_user}) == undefined) {
                su.push({
                    name : d.service_user, 
                    type : "user",
                    id : d.user_id,
                    weight:1
                });
            }
        });

        var nodes = sw.concat(su);

        console.log(nodes);

        nodes.forEach(function(data){
            if(typeof data.linked_to != "undefined") {
                links.push({
                    target: _.findIndex(nodes, function(user) { 
                        return user.id == data.linked_to; 
                    }),
                    source: data.id
                });
            }   
        });

        console.log(links);
        // //console.log(json);console.log(links)
        links.forEach(function(e){
            var sourceNode = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.source})[0];
            var targetNode = nodes.filter(function(n) { return n.id === e.target})[0];
            edges.push({ source: sourceNode, target: targetNode });
        });
        console.log(edges);
        // console.log(nodes);
        force
            .nodes(nodes)
            .links(edges)
            .on("tick", tick)
            .start();

        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
            .data(edges)
            .enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link");

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .call(force.drag);

//          node.append("defs")
            // .append("pattern")
            // .attr("id", function(d){
            //  return "image-" + d.id;
            // })
            // .attr("height", 50)
            // .attr("width", 50)
            // .attr("x", 0)
            // .attr("y", 0)
            // .append("image")
            // .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
            //  return d.image;
            // })
            // .attr('height',60)
         //    .attr('width',60)
         //    .attr('x',0)
         //    .attr('y',0);

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("class", function(d){
                return d.type;
            })
            .attr("r", 25);
            // .on("mouseover", showDetails)
            // .on("mouseout", removeDetails);

        node.append("text")
            .attr("x", 0)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
            .text(function(d){
                //return d.name;
        });

     //     // node.append("svg:a")
     //   //    .attr("xlink:href", function(d){ return "" })
     //   //    .append("text")
     //   //    .attr("dx", 12)
     //   //    .attr("dy", ".35em")
     //   //    .text(function(d) { return d.name})


        function tick(e) {
            var k = 6 * e.alpha;

            // Push sources up and targets down to form a weak tree.
            link
                .each(function(d) { d.source.y -= k, d.target.y += k; })
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node
                .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

            node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
        }

    });
```

Comment: There is no 'layout' for the force layout as its an unordered network. You would have to create a structure yourself and set the positions of each node accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by setting the position along the y axis with `d3.forceY()`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-force/blob/master/README.md#forceY):

> Creates a new positioning force along the y-axis towards the given position y.

So, I created an array using `type` to specify who is user and who is staff:

```
var nodes = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "staff1", "type": "staff"},
    {"id": 2, "name": "staff2", "type": "staff"}, 
    {"id": 3, "name": "user1", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 4, "name": "user2", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 5, "name": "user3", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 6, "name": "staff3", "type": "staff"},
    {"id": 7, "name": "user4", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 8, "name": "user5", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 9, "name": "user6", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 10, "name": "user7", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 11, "name": "user8", "type": "user"},
    {"id": 12, "name": "user19", "type": "user"}
];
```

Then, I used the `type` to set the position:

```
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force('y', d3.forceY((d) => d.type === "staff" ? height/5 : 4*height/5).strength(2))
```

Here is a demo:

```js
var nodes = [
  {"id": 1, "name": "staff1", "type": "staff"},
  {"id": 2, "name": "staff2", "type": "staff"},
  {"id": 3, "name": "user1", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 4, "name": "user2", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 5, "name": "user3", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 6, "name": "staff3", "type": "staff"},
  {"id": 7, "name": "user4", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 8, "name": "user5", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 9, "name": "user6", "type": "user"},
 {"id": 10, "name": "user7", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 11, "name": "user8", "type": "user"},
  {"id": 12, "name": "user19", "type": "user"}
];

var links = [
  {source: 1, target: 8},
  {source: 1, target: 3},
  {source: 1, target: 4},
 {source: 1, target: 9},
 {source: 1, target: 10},
 {source: 1, target: 11},
  {source: 2, target: 5},
  {source: 2, target: 6},
 {source: 2, target: 7},
 {source: 2, target: 12},
  {source: 2, target: 4},
 {source: 2, target: 8},
  {source: 6, target: 7},
  {source: 6, target: 8},
  {source: 6, target: 9},
 {source: 6, target: 5},
  {source: 6, target: 3},
  {source: 6, target: 9},
]

var index = 10;
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    node,
    link;

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
  .force('y', d3.forceY((d) => d.type === "staff" ? height/5 : 4*height/5).strength(2))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide(30))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

update();
function update() {
  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; })

  link = link.enter()
    .append("line")
    .attr("class", "link");

  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })

  node = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .on("click", click)
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 6)
  .attr("fill", (d)=> d.type === "user" ? "blue" : "red")

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  node.append("text")
      .attr("dx", 10)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  simulation
      .nodes(nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(links);
}

function click(d) {
  nodes.push({id: index, name: "server " + index});
  links.push({source: d.id, target: index});
  index++;
  update();
}

function ticked() {
  link
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"; });
}

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart()
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = undefined;
  d.fy = undefined;
}
```

```css
.link {
  stroke: #aaa;
}

.node {
  pointer-events: all;
  stroke: none;
  stroke-width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="400" height="400"></svg>
```

Comment: This is v4, OP is on **v3**, though.